Initiate copy but exit without waiting for it to finish
I'm using boto3 to copy a large object from one bucket to another (3.5 GiB), I'm using the following code:
boto3.client('s3').copy_object(Bucket=dst_bucket, Key=filepath, CopySource={'Bucket': src_bucket, 'Key': filepath})


It works fine, but it takes ~4-5 minute, I don't want to wait around for the copy to be finished I'd rather just initiate the copy and stop the script.
How can I do that ? I thought about launching the copy in a thread and exiting the program after 2second, but it doesn't feel right, surely boto3/aws has a way to do what I'm trying to do ?

You can't "initiate the copy and stop the script" because the local client is performing multi-part uploads. This is where an object is uploaded in multiple 'parts', each up to 5MB. If you stop the script, it will stop the upload.

I would use another thread. The wait is necessary because of its return output. Have you considered using the terminal instead, something in the lines of : 
aws s3 cp s3://source-bucket/your-file-path s3://destination-bucket/your-file-path &  

Using the terminal it only takes 22s which I think is weird. Why does boto takes so much times ?

The AWS CLI also uses boto. However, it probably uploads parts in parallel (using multiple threads) rather than serially.

@JohnRotenstein Thank you, this was indeed the problem. Crazy to think that by default boto3 doesn't take advantage of this.

I've solve the issue using the information on these posts:

Speed up Boto3 file transfer across buckets
How can I increase my AWS s3 upload speed when using boto3?

Turns out boto3 is doing the copy in a really dumb way
Here is the final code for reference:
    botocore_config = botocore.config.Config(max_pool_connections=COPY_WORKERS)
    s3client = boto3.Session().client('s3', config=botocore_config)
    transfer_config = s3transfer.TransferConfig(
        use_threads=True,
        max_concurrency=COPY_WORKERS,
    )
    s3t = s3transfer.create_transfer_manager(s3client, transfer_config)
    s3t.copy(
        bucket=dst_bucket, 
        key=filepath,
        copy_source={'Bucket': src_bucket, 'Key': filepath},
    )
    s3t.shutdown()

It's not returning immediately but it only takes ~20s which is acceptable. I can have my script wait that long
EDIT: Although I'm satisfied with my final code, this doesn't really answer the question which was how to launch it and not wait around. So I will not mark my post as an answer

Presumably you are running your code from the shell, so just run it in the background using &. The Python script itself can't exit until it completes.

@JohnRotenstein I'm running the code in an aws lambda, Ideally I wouldn't want to simply let it run in the background because the longer it run the more money it costs
